# Understand if a curve is parametrized by arc length or not

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves, arc-length

Show that the curve 
 $$\alpha(t)=(t,1+\frac{1}{t},\frac{1}{t}-t),    \quad t\in(0,\infty)$$ 
 is a plane curve.
 
 
I know $\tau$ must be zero for curve being plane. However, I want to determine the given curve is parametrized by arc length or not before starting to solve problem. I thought the magnitude of its first derivative must be 1 to be arc length parametrization. However I couldn't apply my idea since the magnitude is t-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly:

$$\begin{align*}&\alpha'=\left(1\,,\,\,-\frac1{t^2}\,,\,\,-\frac1{t^2}-1\,\right)\\{}\\
&\alpha''=\left(0\,,\,\,\frac2{t^3}\,,\,\frac2{t^3}\right)\\{}\\
&\alpha'''=\left(0\,,\,-\frac6{t^4}\,,\,\,-\frac6{t^4}\right)\end{align*}$$

Also

$$\alpha'\times\alpha''\times\alpha'''=\alpha'\bullet(\alpha''\times\alpha''')=$$

$$=\left(1\,,\,\,-\frac1{t^2}\,,\,\,-\frac1{t^2}-1\,\right)\bullet\left(0,0,0\right)=0\implies$$

$$\tau=\frac{\alpha'\times\alpha''\times\alpha'''}{||\alpha'\times \alpha''||^2}=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I really appreciate if you look at the title but the problem itself. I did the same process as you did and found $\tau$ is $0$.

Comment: Clearly the curve isn't parametrized by arc length. You may want to parametrize it like that, though I doubt greatly the expression will be easier than this one.

Comment: Why "Clearly the curve isn't parametrized by arc length." ?

Comment: Because the integral on $\;||\alpha'||\;$ isn't one, and the integral can't even be defined on zero as then the integral diverges.

Comment: What are boundaries of the integral? I need to know boundaries to see it isn't one. Because the solution of the integration is dependent on t.

Comment: The boundaries are given by the parametrization you gave: $\;(0,\infty)\;$ . This makes things tough at a right neighborhood of zero

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of w.r.t. $s$ or $t$, $\tau =0 $ always, it *cannot* be determined in this vanishing case. (Not repeating derivation made by Joanpemo already). You can detect by finding non-vanishing curvature instead.

Comment: Sometimes curvature is not zero but $\tau=0$. Sometime curvature is zero but $\tau\ne0$